# Gson deserialize child objects based on parent property

Tags: json, gson, deserialization, runtimetypeadapterfactory

I'm trying to deserialize a json response that contains objects which have child objects that can change type based on a property in the parent class. I've seen examples of how to use the type adapter factory for deserializing a child when it's own property type is defined, but cannot figure out how to do it where the defining type is in the parent object. Is this possible?

Example JSON

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "someProperty": "here",
            "anotherProperty": "there",
            "childProperty": {
                "foo": "This property will be here if itemType is 'foo'"
                "abc": "def"
            },
            "itemType": "foo",
        },
        {
            "someProperty": "here",
            "anotherProperty": "there",
            "childProperty": {
                "bar": "This property will be here if itemType is 'bar'"
                "ghi": "jkl"
            },
            "itemType": "bar",
        }
    ],
    "limit": 25,
    "nextCursor": null
}
```

In the above example, the `childPropertyThatChanges` should get deserialized to a different type depending on the value of `itemType`.

---

Given the classes for serialization below:

```
data class FooBarWrapper(
    val items: List<ParentItem>,
    val limit: Int,
    val nextCursor: String?
) : Serializable

data class ParentItem(
    val someProperty: String,
    val anotherProperty: String,
    val childProperty: ChildProperty
)

open class ChildProperty

data class ChildPropertyFoo(
    val foo: String,
    val abc: String
) : ChildProperty()

data class ChildPropertyBar(
    val bar: String,
    val ghi: String
) : ChildProperty()
```

And the type adapters as:

```
val exampleTypeAdapter = RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory
            .of(ChildProperty::class.java, "itemType")
            .registerSubtype(ChildPropertyFoo::class.java, "foo")
            .registerSubtype(ChildPropertyBar::class.java, "bar")

        val exampleGson = GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapterFactory(exampleTypeAdapter)
            .create()

        val deserialized = exampleGson.fromJson(exampleJson, FooBarWrapper::class.java)
```

In the above example, the `childProperty` is never deserialized - it remains null since it cannot infer the type because the `itemType` lives in the parent object.

If I however change the json schema to the below where the itemType is inside the child object, everything deserializes fine.

```
{
    "items": [{
            "someProperty": "here",
            "anotherProperty": "there",
            "childPropertyThatChanges": {
                "foo": "here when itemType is foo",
                "abc": "def",
                "itemType": "foo"
            }
        },
        {
            "someProperty": "here",
            "anotherProperty": "there",
            "childPropertyThatChanges": {
                "bar": "here when itemType is bar",
                "ghi": "jkl",
                "itemType": "bar"
            }
        }
    ],
    "limit": 25,
    "nextCursor": null
}
```

I can't change the json that I'm receiving, so I'm trying to figure out how to create the type adapter so that it works with the type being defined in the parent vs the child object.

Comment: It is not clear what your expected outcome is? It is also not clear where your error is? It is also not clear how you tried to solve your problem?

Comment: The expected outcome is as stated above: The `childPropertyThatChanges` should get deserialized depending on the value in `itemType`. In other words childPropertyThatChanges can be of type `Foo` or `Bar` depending on what the value is for `itemType`. `childPropertyThatChanges` itself has different properties depending on the type.

I have tried using the type adapter factory to define the subtypes but that only seems to work if the type field is contained within the child property, which in my case, it is not - it is in the parent object.

Answer (score 0):

With Gson you could possibly solve this by implementing a custom [`TypeAdapterFactory`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory.html) which does the following:

1. Verify that the requested type is `ParentItem`
2. Create a map from `itemType` String to corresponding `TypeAdapter`, obtained from the `Gson` instance (in the following called "`itemType` map")
3. Get the adapter for `JsonObject` from the `Gson` instance (in the following called "JsonObject adapter")
4. Get a [*delegate adapter*](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/Gson.html#getDelegateAdapter(com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory,com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken)) for `ParentItem` from the `Gson` instance (in the following called "ParentItem adapter") (a *delegate* adapter is needed because otherwise Gson would simply use the current `ParentItem` factory, resulting in infinite recursion)
5. Create and return an adapter which does the following:

   1. Use the JsonObject adapter to read from the reader
   2. Remove the `childProperty` value from the parsed JsonObject and store it in a variable `childPropertyValue`
   3. Remove the `itemType` value and get the corresponding TypeAdapter from the `itemType` map (in the following called "child adapter")
   4. Use the ParentItem adapter on the parsed JsonObject (without the `childPropertyValue`; Gson will not complain about the missing property)
   5. Use the child adapter on `childPropertyValue` and store its result in the `childProperty` of the previously read ParentItem object (this requires making `ParentItem.childProperty` a `var`)
   6. Return the ParentItem object

Then you only need to [register that `TypeAdapterFactory` with a `GsonBuilder`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#registerTypeAdapterFactory(com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory)) (and optionally any custom adapters for `ChildPropertyFoo` or `ChildPropertyBar`).

Here is a sample implementation of the `TypeAdapterFactory`:

```
object ParentItemTypeAdapterFactory : TypeAdapterFactory {
    override fun <T : Any?> create(gson: Gson, type: TypeToken<T>): TypeAdapter<T>? {
        // Only support ParentItem and subtypes
        if (!ParentItem::class.java.isAssignableFrom(type.rawType)) {
            return null
        }

        // Safe cast due to check at beginning of function
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        val delegateAdapter = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type) as TypeAdapter<ParentItem>
        val jsonObjectAdapter = gson.getAdapter(JsonObject::class.java)
        val itemTypeMap = mapOf(
            "foo" to gson.getAdapter(ChildPropertyFoo::class.java),
            "bar" to gson.getAdapter(ChildPropertyBar::class.java),
        )

        // Safe cast due to check at beginning of function
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        return object : TypeAdapter<ParentItem>() {
            override fun read(reader: JsonReader): ParentItem? {
                if (reader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
                    reader.nextNull()
                    return null
                }

                val parentItemValue = jsonObjectAdapter.read(reader)
                val itemType = parentItemValue.remove("itemType").asString
                val childAdapter = itemTypeMap[itemType]
                    ?: throw JsonParseException("Invalid item type: $itemType")
                val childPropertyValue = parentItemValue.remove("childProperty")

                val itemObject = delegateAdapter.fromJsonTree(parentItemValue)
                val childObject = childAdapter.fromJsonTree(childPropertyValue)
                itemObject.childProperty = childObject

                return itemObject
            }

            override fun write(writer: JsonWriter, value: ParentItem?) {
                throw UnsupportedOperationException()
            }
        } as TypeAdapter<T>
    }
}
```

Note that other JSON frameworks provide this functionality out of the box, for example Jackson has [`JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/latest/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.As.html#EXTERNAL_PROPERTY).

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create a type adapter for the `ParentItem` class and within the `JsonDeserializer` subclass based on the value of the `itemType` property deserialize the child object with the correct class (`ChildPropertyFoo` or `ChildPropertyBar`). Then you can simply assign the deserialized object to the `ChildProperty` property. However, this would require `childProperty` to be changed to var in `ParentItem` since it needs to be reassigned. Alternatively, one could construct a complete `ParentItem`.

The code might look something like this:

```
import com.google.gson.*
import java.lang.reflect.Type


internal class ItemDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<ParentItem> {

    override fun deserialize(
        json: JsonElement,
        t: Type,
        jsonDeserializationContext: JsonDeserializationContext
    )
            : ParentItem? {
        val type = (json as JsonObject)["itemType"].asString
        val gson = Gson()
        val childJson = json["childProperty"]
        val childClass = if (type == "foo") ChildPropertyFoo::class.java else ChildPropertyBar::class.java
        val childObject = gson.fromJson<ChildProperty>(childJson, childClass)
        val parent = gson.fromJson(json, ParentItem::class.java) as ParentItem
        parent.childProperty = childObject
        return parent
    }

}
```

The whole thing could of course be generalized by injecting the details like `itemType`, `childProperty` etc. into the `ItemDeserializer` instance, but I rather wanted to show the basic approach.

Anyway, to get a self-contained example for a quick test the call is still missing, which could look like this:

```
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder

fun main() {
    val deserializer = ItemDeserializer()
    val gson = GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(ParentItem::class.java, deserializer).create()
    val deserializedTest = gson.fromJson(json, FooBarWrapper::class.java)
    for (item in deserializedTest.items) {
        when (val childProperty = item.childProperty) {
            is ChildPropertyFoo -> {
                println(childProperty.foo)
                println(childProperty.abc)
            }
            is ChildPropertyBar -> {
                println(childProperty.bar)
                println(childProperty.ghi)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The debug console will then output the following, you can see that the deserialization code gives the desired result:

```
This property will be here if itemType is 'foo'
def
This property will be here if itemType is 'bar'
jkl
```